# Variation of image in JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, width, screen

I tried to solve the problem by myself, but I don't know.

When the width of the screen decreases or expands,
how can I reduce or increase the width of the image in JS?

Comment: Set the width as a percentage in your css. `img {width: 100%}` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had an image in a table and in order to have it adapt to the table I used this class in my css :

```
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to make the image resize with the window in css rather than js.

If your image looks something like this:

```
<div class="Somediv">
    <img src="somesource" class="Someimage"></img>
</div>
```

Your css can look like this:

```
.Somediv {
    width: 50%; //the div will take up 50% of the parent element. You can use 50vw to scale by the width of the window
}

.Someimg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you really want to do it through JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is the official documentation on element.classList which will help you do what your trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript to do this. This can be done through CSS only, You need to set image width to 100% to make it responsive on browser window resize. when you resize your browser window it will automatically takes height according to image width in same aspect ratio.

you need to write a css code like this:

```
img.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem